# My Ubuntu keyboard has gone crazy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard

The keyboard of my Ubuntu laptop (18) has gone crazy. For example, when I type "a", this is the key "Return" which is triggered. I tried to switch from the Belgian keyboard to the English keyboard but that does not change this weird behavior. Would you know what can I do? There is a "a" in my login password but nevertheless I can type my password with the virtual keyboard.

Comment: Boot from a USB drive and check if it works correctly.

Comment: Also if you have a USB keyboard check if that works.